# How to run Karate GatlingDockerJobRunner example?

Tags: karate, distributed-testing

Having already run some promising experiments with Karate-Gatling, we wanted to take it to the next level with Distributed Load Testing across multiple Kubernetes pods and clusters. Following the [docs](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/Distributed-Testing#gatling), I tried to explore the [karate-gatling-demo](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/master/examples/gatling) and espacially the [GatlingDockerJobRunner](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/blob/master/examples/gatling/src/test/java/jobtest/GatlingDockerJobRunner.java).

But with the current versions (since v1.2.0) I don't get the code successfully built. No matter which command, `mvn clean test`, `mvn gatling:test` or even `mvn gatling:test -Dtest=jobtest.GatlingDockerJobRunner` - they always return:

```
Could not resolve dependencies for project com.intuit.karate.examples:examples-gatling:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find com.intuit.karate:karate-gatling:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced
```

Up to v1.1.0, on the other hand, it works on my machine (Ubuntu 20.04 inside Windows 11 WSL2).
Seems like the [`pom.xml`](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/blob/master/examples/gatling/pom.xml) is currently no longer valid?

Edit:

BTW: The docs for this example seems very sparse to me, which may be part of the reason why other people (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62804771/running-karate-gatling-tests-in-distributed-mode-using-docker)) find it difficult to get into. The Maven commands for quick trial don't seem to be documented at all.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, my mistake. Since v1.2.0 you have to hard overwrite the `${karate.version}` variable with the correct value in the pom.xml to build the example:

```
    <!-- please change this when running locally -->
        <karate.version>${project.version}</karate.version>
```

But one question remains:

How do I run the `GatlingDockerJobRunner` example correctly? The command `mvn gatling:test -Dtest=jobtest.GatlingDockerJobRunner` does not seem to be right. Because I would expect it to start up worker nodes in Docker containers, which is not the case.

Edit:

In the [above-mentioned post on distributed Karate-Gatling tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62804771/running-karate-gatling-tests-in-distributed-mode-using-docker), the questioner had found out for himself in a later comment that he could use this command: `mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="jobtest.GatlingDockerJobRunner" -Dexec.classpathScope="test"`.

In fact, this will launch two karate-chrome containers (the workers?). However, this repeatedly throws errors of this type:

```
ERROR com.intuit.karate - java.net.UnknownHostException: host.docker.internal: Name or service not known, http call failed after 35 milliseconds for url: http://host.docker.internal:38287/healthcheck
```

And several minutes later, the process hangs at some point printing `exit status 1; not expected` (without terminating and shutting down the containers):

```
22:31:30.110 [1677965423107-out] DEBUG com.intuit.karate - 21:31:30.109 [main]  ERROR com.intuit.karate - unable to connect to server, aborting
22:31:30.120 [1677965423107-out] DEBUG com.intuit.karate - 2023-03-04 21:31:30,120 INFO exited: karate (exit status 1; not expected)
22:31:30.169 [1677965423107-out] DEBUG com.intuit.karate - 21:31:30.167 [main]  ERROR com.intuit.karate - unable to connect to server, aborting
22:31:30.190 [1677965423107-out] DEBUG com.intuit.karate - 2023-03-04 21:31:30,189 INFO exited: karate (exit status 1; not expected)
```

Given the lack of hints, I wonder if this error pattern is part of the experimental status of the whole approach that I have to accept, or if I am still doing something wrong?

Comment: we would welcome code contributions on github

Comment: But how could I, when I don't even know and understand how the existing one is intended to be used? Don't misunderstand, I would be very happy to help improve where I can. I think the potential of this (distributed) performance testing approach is completely underestimated in user perception so far. But unfortunately also given away.

Comment: I agree. I wish more people used it and contributed better docs and closed the gaps. karate has a lot in it, it is just that hard to make sure everything gets the same priority. we focus on the most commonly used features, I'm sure you will understand